# Can ArrayList be used for readonly purpose in multithreaded environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I have few `ArrayList<T>` containing user defined objects (e.g. `List<Student>, List<Teachers>`). The objects are immutable in nature, i.e. no setters are provided - and also, due to the nature of the problem, "no one" will ever attempt to modify these objects. Once the 'ArrayList' is populated, no further addition/removal of objects is allowed/possible. So List will not dynamically change.

With such given condition, can this data structures (i.e. `ArraList`) be safely used by **multiple threads** (simultaneously)? Each of the thread will just read the object-properties, but there is no "set" operation possible.

So, my question is can I rely on `ArrayList`? If not, what other less expensive data structures can be used in such scenario?

Comment: If the object can not possibly have its state change from different threads, then what could be the problem? Maybe I'm reading this question wrong, but it seems to be a no-brainer. The only issue could be if the states of any of the ArrayList elements could be changed. I would not pass the list to other objects, but either a deep copy of the list or an object of a class that fully encapsulates and protects the list.

Comment: Yes, you can. Try it.

Comment: You may still need some sort of synchronization to ensure the writes that initialize the list *happen-before* the reads, where *happen-before* refers to the [concept defined in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5), or you may run into problems with cache coherency or instruction reordering, causing other threads to see the list partially-constructed.

Answer (score 4):

You can share any objects or data structures between threads if they are never modified after a *safe publication*. As mentioned in the comments, there must be a * happen-before* relationship between the writes that initialize the `ArrayList` and the read by which the other threads acquire the reference.

E.g. if you setup the `ArrayList` completely before starting the other threads or before submitting the tasks working on the list to an `ExecutorService` you are safe.

If the threads are already running you have to use one of the thread safe mechanisms to hand-over the `ArrayList` reference to the other threads, e.g. by putting it on a `BlockingQueue`.

Even simplest forms like storing the reference into a `static final` or `volatile` field will work.

Keep in mind that your precondition of never modifying the object afterwards must always hold. It’s recommended to enforce that constraint by wrapping the list using [`Collections.unmodifiableList(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) and forget about the original list reference before publishing:

```
class Example {
  public static final List<String> THREAD_SAFE_LIST;
  static {
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    // do the setup
    THREAD_SAFE_LIST=Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
  }
}
```

or

```
class Example {
  public static final List<String> THREAD_SAFE_LIST
    =Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to pass the array into each thread. There should be no access errors so long as the array is finished being written to before any thread is possibly getting the information.